# Problem with type constructor in Haskell homework

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have created a datatype and need to make it an instance of the equality typeclass using instance. My datatype consists of values R a b. I want to make `R x y` equal to `R c d` if `x` is equal to `c` and `y` is equal to `d`.

Here is the code that I have written so far. It does not compile.

```
 data Row a b = R a b deriving (Show)
 instance Eq (Row a b)  where
     (R x y) == (R c d) = (x == c) && (y == d)
     _ == _ = False
```

I am thinking it might be wrong because the types a and b do not necessarily have to be in the Equality typeclass. I do not know how to fix this problem.

Comment: The error message actually suggests the way to solve this: `Possible fix: add (Eq a) to the context of the instance declaration [...]`. It's worthwhile to post your error messages too, since they often contain useful information like that.

Answer (score 5):

You can only check if two `R a b`s are equal, given you can check that items of `a` and `b` are equal. So you need to add these as type constraints:

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Row a b)  where
    (R x y) == (R c d) = (x == c) && (y == d)
    _ == _ = False
```

Note however that you do *not* need to implement the `Eq` instance yourself. If you want two `R a b`s to be the same if the data constructor is the same, and their corresponding parameters are the same, then you an just let the compiler derive the instance for your:

```
data Row a b = R a b deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: Thank you. The questions were a bit ambigious in the homeworkproblem and I think it was asked  to solve the problem like you did in the first half of your comment. Now it works as intended. Sadly I cannot upvote you yet, because I lack the reputation.